# increment and decrement number of hotel's visitors in a list using JS JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have list view want to increment and decrement the number of hotel's visitors in a list, clear and accept button using HTML and JS jquery.
Look the link of the  [desirable view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vTiN.png)

```
<form> 
    <div class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="MinusButton()" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
    <input type="number" id="button" value="0"/>
    <div class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="PlusButton()" value="Increase Value">+</div>
</form>

function increaseValue() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value; 
}


function decreaseValue() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
    value--;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to be a question. Just a statement of fact. If this code is causing problems, tells us the problems. If there are errors, tell us the errors. See [ask] for more information about what is expected from questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with functions defined and the one used in `divs` attributes, just use the defined one,

```
<div class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="MinusButton()" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
```

And

```
<div class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="PlusButton()" value="Increase Value">+</div>
```

Also the `document.getElementById('number')` trying to retrieve element that doesn't exists, change the id attribute to `id="number"`, here is a working snippet:

```html
<form> <div class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="MinusButton()" value="Decrease Value">- 
  </div>
  <input type="number" id="number" value="0"/>
  <div class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="PlusButton()" value="Increase Value">+</div>
  </form>

 <script>
 function PlusButton() {
   var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
   value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
   value++;
   document.getElementById('number').value = value; 
}


function MinusButton() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
    value--;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
 </script>
```

Comment: thanks. How can I put increment and decrement number count of the hotel's visitors inside a list of options?  how its shown on the picture

Answer (score 0):

You had messed up your variable names.

1. onClick had to be `increaseValue()` and `decreaseValue()`
2. id of the input field was supposed to be number, not button.

Here's a corrected working version

HTML

```
<form> 
  <div class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()" 
   value="Decrease Value">- 
  </div>
  <input type="number" id="number" value="0"/>
  <div class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue()" value="Increase Value">+</div>
  </form>
```

JS

```
    function increaseValue() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value; }


    function decreaseValue() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
    value--;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
     }
```